# Making angular HTTP call reusable

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my **controller.js**, I have an HTTP GET request that I have to call when my page loads and when a user pulls to refresh.

The way I'm doing it right now is by duplicating the $http code. Is there a way to make this more reusable? I can't figure out how to move it to my **services.js** file and reference it in my controller so that it runs.

```
.controller('GamesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  $http(
  {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/dc6n4edu?apikey=U4SNiysE89aaLXSWRJgHKDZOByqSLM0p',
      headers: {
          'authorization': 'Bearer PW8V4OesZ61tCqSRNpXYtRn5ahcLdclU'
      }
  }).
  success(function (data) {
      $scope.data = data['results']['collection1'];
  });

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    $http(
          {
              method: 'GET',
              url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/dc6n4edu?apikey=U4SNiysE89aaLXSWRJgHKDZOByqSLM0p',
              headers: {
                  'authorization': 'Bearer PW8V4OesZ61tCqSRNpXYtRn5ahcLdclU'
              }
          }).
          success(function (data) {
              $scope.data = data['results']['collection1'];
          })
     .finally(function() {
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
     });
  };
})
```

Comment: Use Services or Factories. Do not forget your add your services module to the main module if u seperated them. Also inject the service (e.g. UserService) in your controller.

Comment: How do I reference a service or factory in the controller? Do I need to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is, make a private function:

```
.controller('GamesCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {
  var doLoad = function() {
      $http(
      {
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/dc6n4edu?apikey=U4SNiysE89aaLXSWRJgHKDZOByqSLM0p',
          headers: {
              'authorization': 'Bearer PW8V4OesZ61tCqSRNpXYtRn5ahcLdclU'
          }
      }).
      success(function (data) {
          $scope.data = data['results']['collection1'];
      }).finally(function() {
       $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
     });;
  };

  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    doLoad();
  };

  doLoad();
})
```

A more detailed answer might be to extract it into a service:

```
.service('KimonoSvc',function($http) {
    return {
      get: function() {
         return $http(
         {
             method: 'GET',
             url: 'https://www.kimonolabs.com/api/dc6n4edu?apikey=U4SNiysE89aaLXSWRJgHKDZOByqSLM0p',
             headers: {
                 'authorization': 'Bearer PW8V4OesZ61tCqSRNpXYtRn5ahcLdclU'
             }
         });
      }
    };
})
.controller('GamesCtrl', function ($scope, KimonoSvc) {
  var doGet = function() {
    KimonoSvc.get().
         success(function (data) {
             $scope.data = data['results']['collection1'];
         }).finally(function() {
          $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');
        });
  };
  $scope.doRefresh = function() {
    doGet();
  };

  doGet();
})
```

Comment: `$scope.doRefresh = doLoad;` and `$scope.doRefresh = doGet;`. No need for extra anonymous functions.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you could do that, and then call `$scope.doRefresh()` at the end of the controller. I like the separate functions, stylistically (named, not anonymous).

Comment: no you misunderstood me.. its fine to create a function .. just do not use another to apply it to the `doRefresh`. `$scope.doRefresh = function() {doGet();};` could become `$scope.doRefresh = doGet;`

Comment: Oh, I see what you are saying. Yeah, I still prefer it as a wrapper, because I often find there is a need to wrap it in some kind of logic, or error-checking, etc. But if it is a straight pass-through, then, yeah, just `$scope.doRefresh = doGet;`